# Static Gmaps in winform

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, google-maps-api-3

Im trying to load a google static map in a winform. I found a control online that would helpme but i cant get it working. i got the control from [Here](http://gglgeo.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Static%20Google%20Map%20WinForm%20Control). i was not able to drag on the control on to the form like others. i have also email the dev of the control but have not heard back yet.

Any help would be Great. 
Thank

here is my code

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim gmap As New CtpGglMap.Impl.StaticGMap
    gmap.Center.Address = "New york ,NY"
    gmap.Zoom = 14
    gmap.Height = 400
    gmap.Width = 600
    gmap.Sensor = False

    PictureBox1.Image = gmap
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working.

```
 Dim gmap As New CtpGglMap.Impl.StaticGMap
    Dim temp As New GMarker
    Dim temp2 As New GMarker
    gmap.Center = New GeoPointImpl(41.5442847, -73.8732391)
    gmap.Zoom = 14


    gmap.Height = 334
    gmap.Width = 362
    gmap.Sensor = False
    TextBox1.Text = GetDrivingDirectionFromGoogle("fishkill ,ny", "41.5442847, -73.8732391")

    temp.Point = New GeoPointImpl(41.5442847, -73.8732391)
    temp.SetMap(gmap)

    'CREATE A BITMAP FROM THE MEMORY STREAM
    PictureBox1.Image = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(gmap.Fetch)
```